# how to use the number returned by arglistid()

Tags: argument-list

In the doc little is said about this number. Can we retrieve the entire arglist using this number and get all the versions of arglist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great question! The only *existing* use I can determine from the docs is that it allows you to find out whether a window is currently using a local `arglist` or the global one.

However, it looks as though it's just the first step of some more extensive changes that allow you to use the number to manipulate the lists in use.

This code has already been written (see [arglists.patch in this repository](https://github.com/coot/vim_patches#arglistspatch)) but hasn't yet been accepted into the main Vim codebase: you can see it mentioned in `:help todo` by searching for `arglists`.

Comment: Thanks, @Rich. Perhaps it is just in development and does not have any usage now. I used neovim and when I type `:help todo`, it jumps to the tag `netrw-todo` for `netrw` plugin. Very wired.

Comment: Neovim is development is lead by different people from Vim development, so it makes sense not for them to use the same todo list. The [Vim todo.txt is online here](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/todo.txt.html#todo.txt). (The [NeoVim Roadmap is here](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/todo.txt.html#todo.txt).)